# Display plugin entityreference is not available

Tags: 7, views

I'm not sure if this is a Views issue or an Entity reference issue, so I'm cross-posting here to see if I can find an answer.

I'm trying to export a view from my testing & development site, to our production site, but I keep running into issues, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

To the best of my knowledge I've got the exact same setup on both sites - modules are all the same, and all have the same versions for both `Views` and `Entityreference`.

However, when I try to import the view on our production site I get the following errors:

```
Relationship handler node.reverse_field_plan_document_attachment_node is not available.
Display plugin entityreference is not available.
Relationship handler node.reverse_field_plan_document_attachment_node is not available.
Unable to import view.
```

I'm stumped. I have no idea where else to look. I'm assuming it's a simple issue with a setting somewhere, but I can't find it. Everything works perfectly without issue on our testing site, and doing wholesale database swap is not an option.

When I go to create a new view on our production site, I don't even have the option to add an entity reference display:

[image: Views UI missing the Entity Reference display option]

Initially, I tried to use the features module to move the feature set from the testing site to the production site, but that was an enormous mess. I completely uninstalled the features module, and all the modules I created with it in effort to try to get this stuff working. After uninstalling all that stuff, I'm still left without an option to even create an Entityreference display with Views, and obviously cannot import my view either.

Can you help?

Comment: How are you checking that the modules config is the same? Did you check which modules are enabled or just which ones you have on the file system? What happens if you disable/enable the Entityreference module? Maybe the enabled status got borked when importing the db?

Comment: I went through checking each module side by side to insure that all modules are properly enabled in both places. The way I understand it, I should really only need Views and Entity Reference modules enabled to facilitate this but I went through all of them on both sites.

Answer (score 0):

So - after getting another pair of eyes on this the issue is resolved. Somehow, the entityreference module was only partially installed and was missing the views directory (along with a couple other things) but was otherwise *fully functional* outside of the issue as described above.

Not sure how the module would be working for other purposes, not throw any errors *at all* without those directories but that was the case.

Thanks to Matt Glaman for the help tracking down the problem.